tex4ht warning cannot determine size of graphic
With tex4ebook I get warnings for tex4ht when includegraphics, and the images are squared in the epub and not rectangular like in the pdf, so they seem a bit distorted.
TeX4ht warning --- Cannot determine size of graphic in "Abbildungen/ Figs/Figure10_5.xbb" (no BoundingBox)
For example, I use such code:
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Abbildungen/Figs/Figure1_1.jpg}
Is there a way to avoid these warnings? And get the size relations in the epub like in the pdf?

Is it particular images or all of them? Can you reproduce with a standard image in an example?

All images are involved with this warning.

Graphics driver that TeX4ht uses for image inclusion needs .xbb files to determine image dimensions, as the warning says:
TeX4ht warning --- Cannot determine size of graphic in "Figure10_5.xbb" (no BoundingBox)

You can create this file using the ebb -x command:
$ ebb -x Abbildungen/Figs/*.jpg
$ ebb -x Abbildungen/Figs/*.png

Repeat this process for all directories that contain images and for all used image types.
See also the TeX4ht documentation for more tips on image handling.


Thank you, it is great to read that there is a solution. But I do not know where I should place the $ ebb -x Abbildungen/Figs/*.jpg code? Within latex and the includegraphic? Where to put it? In the config file?

@Thomkrates no, it needs to be executed on the command line, in the directory with your TeX file. And without the $ character, it is just a convention to show that a command should be run on the command line

Yes, thank you. This works. Great!
